# Intersection of parametric function with coordinate axes

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, graphing-functions, parametric, maple

Me and a friend could need some assistance:

[image: Given function + Plot]

> $$x(t)=t\cos t$$
>   $$y(t)=t\sin t$$

We've been given the assignment to find where our parametric function intersects the x- and y-axes. But we can't really seem to find any solutions in our CAT programs.

We've got a solution by defining $y(t)=0$ and solving for $t$ which only gives us 0…

Answer (score 1):

the equation $$t\sin(t)=0$$ gives us $$t=0$$ or $$t=k\pi$$ with $$k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

You may find the $y$ and $x$ intersections as follows:

```
[> restart:
   inty := {solve([t*sin(t) = 0, -10 < t, t < 10], t, allsolutions, explicit)};
   intx := {solve([t*cos(t) = 0, -10 < t, t < 10], t, allsolutions, explicit)};



inty := {{t = 0}, {t = Pi}, {t = -3*Pi}, {t = -2*Pi}, {t = -Pi}, {t = 2*Pi}, {t = 3*Pi}}

intx := {{t = 0}, {t = -(5/2)*Pi}, {t = -(3/2)*Pi}, {t = -(1/2)*Pi}, {t = (1/2)*Pi}, {t = (3/2)*Pi}, {t = (5/2)*Pi}}
```

Answer (score 0):

*HINT*:

- $\sin t=0$ if $t=0,\pm\pi,\pm2\pi,\dots$
- $\cos t=0$ if $t=\pm\frac12\pi,\pm\frac32\pi,\pm\frac52\pi,\dots$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Intersection with the $x$-axis means $y = 0$:
$$
x = t \cos t \\
0 = t \sin t
$$
The easiest solution is at $t = 0$. If $t \ne 0$ you can use
$$
0 = \sin(t) \Rightarrow t \in  \{ \pm \pi, \pm 2 \pi, \pm 3 \pi \}
$$
(because you can divide the second equation by $t$ on both sides) to have $t \in [-10, 10]$.

Intersection with the $y$-axis means $x = 0$:
$$
0 = t \cos t \\
y = t \sin t
$$
Again $t = 0$ is a solution. For $t \ne 0$ we use
$$
0 = \cos t \Rightarrow t \in \{ \pm\pi/2, \pm 3 \pi /2, \pm 5 \pi /2 \}
$$

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the other solutions with Maple, use the **allsolutions** option to the **solve** command: **solve(t*sin(t) = 0, allsolutions)**.

Comment: I tried to do so in Maple but it just gave me a result saying: 
solve (t*cos(t)=0,allsolutions)= 0, 1/2*pi + pi_Z6~

Comment: Yes, that's correct, except that **pi** should be **Pi** and the last term should be transcribed as **Pi*_Z6~**. The **_Z6** is a parameter which can be replaced by any integer to produce a solution (a value of **t** satisfying the equation). The **~** appended to **_Z6** indicates that an assumption has been placed on this variable---in this case that it is integer.

Comment: Sorry I was on the phone when I wrote it but I did indeed use a Pi symbol in Maple.

Take a look at this picture: http://imgur.com/YXub9WW